# How can I avoid specifying potentially conflicting constraints

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout, uistackview

I am trying to create all of my views in my `UICollectionViewCell` programatically. The views currently lay out **correctly**.

I have a vertical `stackView` that contains two `UILabels` and a `UIImageView`.

The views do not have a fixed content size and are all variable.

If you see in my code, I am setting the `leading` and `trailing` constraints of my `UIStackView` with a constant of 8.0 from the `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. Because of this, I have to set the `widthAnchor` to be -16.0 (otherwise the cell does not lay out correctly). Is there a way I can avoid specifying this in two places? For example, if I set the `leading` to be 14.0 points from the `leading`, then I will have to make sure I remember to change my width to be -20.0, otherwise the contents will spill over.

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    /// Check if views already have constraints
    if !viewsHaveConstraints {
        viewsHaveConstraints = true


        /* 
        Here I set the hugging and compression priority for the 3 views in the UIStackView
        */


        let margins = safeAreaLayoutGuide

        /*  Set vstackView constraints */

        /// vStackView width anchor equal to width of margin less constant
        vStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true

        /// vStackView leading anchor constraint
        vStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true

        /// vStackView trailing anchor constraint
        vStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true

        vStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

Comment: If you have constraints for the leading and trailing anchor then the width constraint is redundant anyway, just remove it.

Comment: @dan you were right. I can avoid conflicting my constraints by not adding a redundant one :p thanks. If you want to submit as an answer I'll accept it